# actionscript httpservice authentication popup

Tags: authentication, actionscript, flex3

when using the Flex mx.rpc.http.HTTPService object to send a request that requires authentication I'm setting the headers to do authentication (which works fine..) but, in the case where the wrong authentication details are sent, an operating system level popup is being seen.

Apparently on the URLRequest object there is a property: 'authenticate' which can be set to false to prevent this.  Is there any equivalent for the HTTPService object that would prevent these operating system level popups?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is interesting. Can you provide some sample code so we can replicate this problem to help answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is basically - no.

You have to use URLRequest to manage that particular issue.  End of story.